# Change Tablist names for each individual Player. (Spigot)

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit, bungeecord

## Hello

I am currently making a Minecraft SkyWars-Plugin and want to make a better looking tablist.

---

### The Problem:

Lets say you have ***PlayerA*** and ***PlayerB***. If ***PlayerA*** looks on the tablist, his name should be green and the name of ***PlayerB*** should be red.

But if ***PlayerB*** looks at his tablist, ***PlayerB***'s name should be green and ***PlayerA***'s name should be red.

So basically your own name should be marked as green (Color code 'a') and the opponents should have a red name (Color code 'c').

---

How do I achieve that? Do I send packages to each Player for his tablist? If so, which packages should/can I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved in two ways.

If you want to show per-player visible colors **only** in a tablist, you can use `Player Info` packet (specification https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Player_Info) for tablist content modification. Full valid code can be very volume, so i give you an algorithm (below I mean "packet" is `Player Info` packet):

1. Send packet with action `remove player` (see *wiki* for action list) with **PlayerA**.uuid to PlayerA
2. Send packet with action `remove player` with **PlayerB**.uuid to PlayerA
3. Repeat **1** and **2**, but send packets to playerB.
4. Send packet with: action `add player`, **PlayerA**.uuid and colored **PlayerA's** display name for PlayerA (which in your case is green) to PlayerA.
5. Send packet with: action `add player`, **PlayerB**.uuid and colored **PlayerB's** display name for PlayerA (which in your case is red) to PlayerA.
6. Repeat **4** and **5**, but send packets to playerB and invert colors.

*For packets management you can use ProtocolLib plugin.*

If you want to show per-player visible colors in tablist and above the head, you can use similar algorithm with scoreboard teams packets. Or you can try to find implemented plugin api for per-player visible prefixes.